# Issue Present View Controller with Custom URL Scheme

Tags: ios, swift2

In Storyboard: NavigationController -> UITableViewController

**appdelegate.swift**

```
  func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let navVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("navViewController") as! UINavigationController

        if let tableVC = navVC.topViewController as? UITableViewController {
            tableVC.searchText = // URL query param
        }        
            self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(navVC, animated: false, completion: nil)            
    }

    return true
}
```

The problem was when I enter with custom URL in Safari in second time

```
appUrl://search?q=...
```

The first time it is Ok, open correctly, but if I come back to Safari to open another URL I got

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x7fb1fb090000> on <UINavigationController: 0x7fb1fa843400> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the `rootViewController` tries to present two `UIViewController` which triggers the warning message.How about presenting the second `UIViewController` on the **presented** `UIViewController`.

```
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let navVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("navViewController") as! UINavigationController

    if let tableVC = navVC.topViewController as? UITableViewController {
        tableVC.searchText = // URL query param
    }        
        self.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController?.presentViewController(navVC, animated: false, completion: nil)            
}

return true
}
```

Comment: Well this work's!! Thanks, now I have to fix other problems =D

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool
{
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let navVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("navViewController") as! UINavigationController

    if let tableVC = navVC.topViewController as? UITableViewController
    {
        tableVC.searchText
    }

    if let presented = window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController?.presentedViewController
    {
        presented.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: {
            self.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController?.presentViewController(navVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
        })
    }
    else
    {
        self.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController?.presentViewController(navVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: Xcode complain about: 
'?' must be followed by a call, member lookup, or subscript

Comment: I changed a little bit. I'm on my iPad and cannot access to my MacBook. ;(

Comment: I changed to :  (self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController).presentViewController(navVC, animated: false, completion: nil) but still getting the warning

Comment: Sounds great! :) You may select my answer!